# Ftplib ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused (python 3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I have a script that should connect to a FTP

```
from ftplib import FTP

with FTP('IP') as ftp:
   ftp.login(user='my user', passwd='my password')
   ftp.cwd('/MY_DIR')
   ftp.dir()
```

I have an error :
   `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

---

The ftp is an EC2 with vsftpd

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
pasv_address=IP
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
```

### Already tried :

The code work on other FTP with and without TLS (hosted on 1and1, OVH...)

---

I tried this script in NodeJS

```
const ftpClient = require('ftp-client');

const client = new ftpClient({
   host: "IP",
   port: 21,
   user: "My user", // defaults to "anonymous"
   password: "My password" // defaults to "@anonymous"
});

client.connect(() => {

  client.download('/MY_DIR/file','/tmp/file', (res) => {
        console.log(res)
  })
});
```

Works perfectly fine so I exclude a firewall problem

---

I have tried enable TLS

```
ssl_enable=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
```

then 
    sudo service vsftpd restart

and use
`FTP_TLS` instead of `FTP`
but did not work

---

Also I tried disable passive mode by setting

```
pasv_enable=NO
```

then 
    `sudo service vsftpd restart`

and `ftp.set_pasv(False)`

didn't work either

Comment: Related: [Cannot list FTP directory using ftplib – but FTP client works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55814722/850848).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

After using filezilla to debug the method, turn out that our FTP returned 0.0.0.0 despite we defined in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
pasv_adress=IP
```

this post helped us : https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=52408

You have to comment

```
listen_ipv6=YES
```

and enable

```
listen=YES
```

in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

---

Also you can override the ftplib's class FTP if you can't access to vsftpd.conf of the FTP

```
class CustomFTP(ftplib.FTP):

    def makepasv(self):
        if self.af == socket.AF_INET:
            host, port = ftplib.parse227(self.sendcmd('PASV'))
        else:
            host, port = ftplib.parse229(self.sendcmd('EPSV'), self.sock.getpeername())

        if '0.0.0.0' == host:
            """ this ip will be unroutable, we copy Filezilla and return the host instead """
            host = self.host
        return host, port
```

to force the previous host if `'0.0.0.0'` is send

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it saved me a ton of time!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I also had to catch if the returned host was not starting with "192.168". I guess the server I connect to is wrongly configured...

Comment: The vsftpd issue is discussed in details here: [vsftpd returns 0,0,0,0 in response to PASV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41046707/850848).